# How to restrict the upload image ratio to 16:9 in codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

Here is the code I used for uploading an image.

```
$this->load->library('upload');
$ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$img_name = now() . "." . $ext;

$imgConfig['upload_path'] = $this->image_path;
$imgConfig['file_name'] = $img_name;
$imgConfig['max_size'] = '2048';
$imgConfig['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|bmp';
$imgConfig['overwrite'] = FALSE;
$this->upload->initialize($imgConfig);

if ($this->upload->do_upload("image_url")) {
    $this->Playlist_model->update_playlist($insert_id, array("image_url" => $img_name));
}
```

And the frontend is simply a

```
<input type = 'file' >
```

The problem is , as the image upload should be an video thumbnail, what should I do to implement the upload? e.g using plugin in frontend to restrict/ crop (any recommendation)

Also, in server side how can I check?

Comment: Try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255773/php-crop-image-to-fix-width-and-height-without-losing-dimension-ratio)

Comment: and this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319304/resizing-and-cropping-image-with-gd-while-retaining-aspect-ratio)

Comment: Thanks, the link seems to keep the image ratio and resize, any case for specific 16:9?

Comment: @user782104 Why not just verifying that using javascript before even thinking to send it to the server ?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
maintain_ratio
```

it the Preference you to maintain ratio

```
Specifies whether to maintain the original aspect ratio when resizing or use hard values.
```

For more details

- https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html
- [Resize image according to width only & crop Extra Height , Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638940/resize-image-according-to-width-only-crop-extra-height-codeigniter)
- [Resizing and cropping in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775912/resizing-and-cropping-in-codeigniter)

Comment: would you mind explain briefly about how to crop the 16:9 image? eg.  calculate the corresponding width / height

Comment: But how to specify ratio like 16:9.it will resize image according to image size not in ny fixed ratio

Comment: to crop usually you want to do that on the users side. if they are satisfied with the look then you should resize.. I think that is the idea overall for this type of thing. You shouldn't allow the computer to crop something automatically without direction :(

Answer (score 1):

```
$data_upload = $this->upload->data();

$file_name = $data_upload["file_name"];
$file_name_thumb = $data_upload['raw_name'].'_thumb' . $data_upload['file_ext'];

$this->load->library('image_lib');
$config_resize['image_library'] = 'gd2';    
$config_resize['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
$config_resize['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config_resize['master_dim'] = 'height';//Check link 1 below
$config_resize['quality'] = "100%";
$config_resize['source_image'] = './' . $user_upload_path . $file_name;

//for 16:9 width is 640 and height is 360(Check link 2 below)
$config_resize['height'] = 360;
$config_resize['width'] = 640;
$this->image_lib->initialize($config_resize);
$this->image_lib->resize();

$data["file_name_url"] = base_url() . $user_upload_path . $file_name;
$data["file_name_thumb_url"] = base_url() . $user_upload_path . $file_name_thumb;
```

**Notes**:

1. **index function**: load the view upload_example to display the upload form.
2. **do_upload function**: save uploaded file to web server, resize the file and display result.

   - **userfile**: is the file input name we created in the upload form.
   - **user_upload_path**: is the location on web server to save uploaded files. It must be writable.
   - **maintain_ratio = TRUE**:  to maintain aspect ratio
   - **master_dim = height**:  the height is used as the hard value
   - **height and width** resized image’s height and maintain ratio.

**CodeIgniter View to display resized image**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CodeIgniter Upload And ReSize Image Maintain Ratio</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    if(isset($upload_error))
    {
        echo $upload_error;
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <strong>Thumbnail:</strong>
        <p><img src="<?php echo $file_name_thumb_url;?>" /></p>

        <strong>Original:</strong>
        <p><img src="<?php echo $file_name_url;?>" /></p>
        <?php
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Links

1. [Codeigniter Preferences](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html?highlight=image%20manipulation%20class#preferences)
2. [16:9 ratio width and height](http://size43.com/jqueryVideoTool.html)
3. [refer this article](http://4rapiddev.com/php/codeigniter-upload-and-resize-image-maintain-ratio/)

Comment: Resizing would lead to **stretching** as its not originally 16:9

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="up.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="files" multiple id="files"/>
</form>
```

This is `up.php`

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']);
//i gave sample ratio 2.5 and 0.4 you can adjust yourself
if(abs($width / $height) >= 2.5 || abs($width / $height) <= 0.4) {
echo 'Image ratio is invalid';
exit ;
}
```